# The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This could initially was working but after firebase update, it is now giving me this error. I have  added asterisks to the part giving the error. The error message has been added beneath the code.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Record {
  final String name;
  final int totalVotes;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  Record.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map['name'] != null),
        assert(map['totalVotes'] != null),
        name = map['name'],
        totalVotes = map['totalVotes'];

  Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(**snapshot.data**, reference: snapshot.reference);

  @override
  String toString() => "Record<$name:$totalVotes>";
}

class Voters {
  String uid;
  String voteId;
  String markedVoteOption;
}
```

The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

Comment: where do you get that error?

Comment: Where I have added the asterisk. ***    This is it.                                                                                            Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(***snapshot.data***, reference: snapshot.reference);

Comment: Please don't post plain error messages in the title. Look at the clutter on the right.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try the following:

```
  Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data(), reference: snapshot.reference);
```

`data()` is a method:

```
  /// Contains all the data of this [DocumentSnapshot].
  Map<String, dynamic> data() {
    return _CodecUtility.replaceDelegatesWithValueInMap(
        _delegate.data(), _firestore);
  }
```

that returns a `Map<String, dynamic>`

Comment: Based on the answer you gave, I was able to manipulate it and find my way around it. You can check my answer below. @Peter Haddad

Comment: @KobbyDiscount no dont use that second code snippet that I should you.. Im just showing you the code here for the `data()` method https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_snapshot.dart#L38

Comment: @KobbyDiscount All you have to do is this `Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data(), reference: snapshot.reference);`

Comment: Hi, I am still getting the same error after trying all the solutions here and on other pages

Answer (score 5):

It's because [DocumentSnapshot.data()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) is a function that returns `Map<String, dynamic>`.

So, the answer is:

```
  Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data(), reference: snapshot.reference);
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```
Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
          : this.fromMap(snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>, reference: snapshot.reference);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently all that was needed was parentheses on the maps

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Record {
  final String name;
  final int votes;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  Record.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map(), {this.reference})
      : assert(map()['name'] != null),
        assert(map()['votes'] != null),
        name = map()['name'],
        votes = map()['votes'];

  Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);

  @override
  String toString() => "Record<$name:$votes>";
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error after trying all the solutions mentioned

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Record {
  final String name;
  final int totalVotes;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  Record.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map(), {this.reference})
      : assert(map()['name'] != null),
        assert(map()['totalVotes'] != null),
        name = map()['name'],
        totalVotes = map()['totalVotes'];

  Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);

  @override
  String toString() => "Record<$name:$totalVotes>";
}

class Voters {
  String uid;
  String voteId;
  String markedVoteOption;
}


 /// Contains all the data of this [DocumentSnapshot].
  Map<String, dynamic> data() {
    return _CodecUtility.replaceDelegatesWithValueInMap(
        _delegate.data(), _firestore);
  }
```