# The argument type 'Object? Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to import player data from Firestore...This is my first venture into online databases

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/7426050-firebase-tutorial-for-flutter-getting-started

I receive the error in the title. Can anyone help me please?

It seams to be snap.data which is causing the problem. My research has shown that snapshot.data is a function but I don't understand how to fix the issue in my case.

a similar question is answewred here:

[The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63597313/the-argument-type-mapstring-dynamic-function-cant-be-assigned-to-the-par)

However that question uses MAP and my tutorial uses JSON. Are they the same thing?

Apologies for my naivety if they are the same thing.

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'person.dart';

class Player extends Person {
  final int _shirtNumber;
  final DateTime _dateOfBirth;

  DocumentReference _reference;

  Player(String _firstName, String _secondName, this._shirtNumber,
      this._dateOfBirth, this._reference)
      : super(_firstName, _secondName);

  int get shirtNumber => _shirtNumber;

  DateTime get dateOfBirth => _dateOfBirth;

  int get ageInDays => DateTime.now().difference(_dateOfBirth).inDays;

  int get age => ageInDays ~/ 365.25;

  DocumentReference get reference => _reference;

  factory Player.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {

    Player newPlayer = Player.fromJson(snapshot.data);
    newPlayer._reference = snapshot.reference;
    return newPlayer;
  }

  factory Player.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) => _playerFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _playerToJson(this);
}

//Helpers

Player _playerFromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
  return Player(
      json['firstName'] as String,
      json['secondName'] as String,
      json['shirtNumber'] as int,
      json['dateOfBirth'] as DateTime,
      json['documentID'] as DocumentReference);
}

Map<String, dynamic> _playerToJson(Player instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'firstName': instance.firstName,
      'secondName': instance.secondName,
      'shirtNumber': instance.shirtNumber,
      'dateOfBirth': instance.dateOfBirth,
    };
```

Comment: Can you try snapshot.data() ?

Comment: thank you for your input. IF i modify the line to [Player newPlayer = Player.fromJson(snapshot.data());] I get the same error :(