# FlutterFire DocumentSnapshot.data() is returning Object?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm in the process of upgrading my libraries in my flutter app as well as move to null-safety. I'm using cloud_firestore version 2.2.1.

In my model i have a factory method that takes a documentsnapshot, I'm receiving the error

> A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

```
factory Account.fromDoc(DocumentSnapshot doc) {

    if(doc.exists)
    {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data();
      ...

    }
```

Documentation at https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/ states that

> If the document exists, you can read the data of it by calling the
> data method, which returns a Map<String, dynamic>, or null if it does
> not exist

So I'm not sure why it is returning it as a type of Object? when I'm expecting Map<String, dynamic> or what I need to do. How can I get this to work ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63597313/the-argument-type-mapstring-dynamic-function-cant-be-assigned-to-the-par) help?

Answer (score 3):

Basically you have to add a type to the DocumentSnapshot, this occured to me and this is how I solved it:

```dart
factory Account.fromDoc(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc) { // here the type should be specified

    if(doc.exists)
    {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data();
      ...

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yazeed. I'm getting a "A value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'." Since I'm checking if the doc.exists I'm expecting it to be non null value. However, the return is showing a possible null - did you have to a null check after ?